# CSS last-child doesn't work for me

Tags: html, css

I try to learn every day and I found a tutorial where the teacher selected the first-child from list-group-item to change color.

I wanted to play with this and to select the last:child from list-group-item, to change the text-decoration rule, only for the span(More), but doesn't work. With the css, that I put here too, the More word is not underlined.

How can I do it?

```css
.list-group-item {
        padding: 0px;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    .list-group-item:last-child {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="sidebar">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="sidebar-inner  ">
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <div class="float-left imageIcon">
                <img src="../images/sidebar_icon" class="img-responsive" alt="Icon">
              </div>
              <div class="float-right textDesc">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">My Title</h4>
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Description</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <span>More...</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <div class="float-left imageIcon">
                <img src="../images/sidebar_icon" class="img-responsive" alt="Icon">
              </div>
              <div class="float-right textDesc">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">My Title</h4>
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Description</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <span>More...</span>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where ur writing this styles in css or in html

Comment: in the file style.css

Comment: plz add Refference that file in html...and clean the soluton Run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `text-decoration: underline;` not `text-decoration: underlined;`.

**EDIT:** Added a Snippet:

```css
.list-group-item {
 padding: 0px;
 margin-left: 20px;
}
.list-group-item:last-child {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="sidebar-inner  ">
   <div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item">
     <div class="float-left imageIcon">
      <img src="../images/sidebar_icon" class="img-responsive" alt="Icon">
     </div>
     <div class="float-right textDesc">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">My Title</h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">Description</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item">
     <span>More...</span>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item">
     <div class="float-left imageIcon">
      <img src="../images/sidebar_icon" class="img-responsive" alt="Icon">
     </div>
     <div class="float-right textDesc">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">My Title</h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">Description</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item">
     <span>More...</span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: O, I see, but still, doesn't work. I don't see More word underlined. I get the whole box .list-group-item underlined now :)

Comment: Thank you @MD5HashBrowns :).